# C# XtraTreeList's AppendNode method takes too much time

Tags: c#, object, devexpress, nodes, xtratreelist

I'm having a lot of troubles with adding nodes to a `XtraTreeList`.

The method I use is `TreeList.AppendNode` (more info about the method [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_AppendNodetopic)).

**Actual Results :**

If I have a class called `MyClass` and I want to add a node to an existing node in my `XtraTreeList`.

If I do something like :

```
// tlTest is the XtraTreeList
tlTest.AppendNode(new MyClass(/* Some Arguments */), parentNode);
```

Noting is printed on the screen.

BUT, if I do something like :

```
// tlTest is the XtraTreeList
tlTest.AppendNode(new object[] (){/* Some Arguments without cast */}, parentNode);
```

This seems to work perfectly well !

**Problem :**

The problem with the second way of doing things is that it takes soooo much time / ressources for something like 200 child nodes to add. And I'm wondering if it has something to do with dynamic casting ...

**Question :**

Is there a better way of doing this ? Keeping the code as it is would not be a good idea as adding 200 child nodes takes about 6/7 seconds (which is a real pain for the end user).

Comment: Why you dont use the first way? And what happened if you create object array at first and then loop each item and add it to the Nodes?

Comment: Like I said @Sebi, nothing is printed on the screen if I use the first way ... It seems that the tree does not recognize anything else than `object []` ... Even in the official doc link above, they use a `object []` to print two strings .. Question is : why they do not use a `List<string>` for instance ...

Comment: Oh sorry you forgot the "h" in nothing ;-) Did you try to handle the treelist with the DataSource Property? I never used this sorry. But with DataSource you should be able to use you own class.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to use the [TreeList.BeginUnboundLoad](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_BeginUnboundLoadtopic) and [TreeList.EndUnboundLoad](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_EndUnboundLoadtopic) methods to prevent unnecessary updates when you add multiple nodes in unbound mode.

From [help-article](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_BeginUnboundLoadtopic):

> The BeginUnboundLoad and EndUnboundLoad methods should be used to
>   avoid excessive internal data updates when adding, deleting and
>   modifying nodes in unbound mode. In bound mode, use the
>   LockReloadNodes and UnlockReloadNodes methods instead.